# AppAuth or manually implementing OAuth2.0 in Android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to understand - what is the use of [AppAuth SDK](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) really?
I have a website (which acts as the User Agent in OAuth2.0) where the user inserts his credentials.
I pass this website a Redirect URL as a parameter, and once the user passes the verification process inside the website, the website sends the redirect url along with an Access Token.

Now if I'm not mistaken I have a few options :

1. WebView - simply catching the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` callback, and retrieving the access token from the url. What are the cons of this approach?
2. doing the same with Chrome Custom Tabs ?
3. doing the same with Trusted Web Activity ?
4. Integrating the AppAuth SDK somehow, but what does it really give us that the former approaches don't do or don't handle?

Does it handle the fact that I need a Digital Asset Link maybe ? Do I even really need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppAuth` is just a library which has few pre defined methods which are quite common for any OAuth provider. For example Microsoft uses `MSAL` which is based on AppAuth and helps in authenticating a user and getting the access token.

However you can definitely make your own implementation without using `AppAuth`. You can have a ChromeCustomTab open and listen to redirect URL.

e.g.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.LoginActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/BaseTheme.Login">

    <intent-filter android:label="@string/activity_login">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
              android:host="oauth2redirect"
              android:scheme="com.example.appname" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As you can see above, the login page which opens ChromeCustomTab listens for redirect URL i.e. `com.example.appname://oauth2redirect` which will contain the auth code. Your implementation might vary but core principle remains same.

You can also have a look [here](https://joebirch.co/android/oauth-on-android-with-custom-tabs/) to know more on usage of ChromeCustomTab for OAuth.

Comment: Thank you. How do you ensure that this scheme you defined, can only call/invoke your app, and not any app on the device that matches the scheme in the manifest ?
Use Digital Asset Link? In that case, why would you prefer to use ChromeCustomTab over Trusted Web Activity ?

Comment: Ideally we use package name as scheme (for native apps) as no other package with same signature can exist in Google Play store hence keeping uniqueness. And the use of CCT is because it has a warmup option which instantly opens the login page by pre-caching it in background. AppAuth and MSAL also use CCT to do authentication.

Comment: but if a user has another app installed on the device, where one of its activities has the same scheme as your app's package name, wouldn't that be possible to bypass that restriction for a malicious app? because essentially you will have two apps that have activities that can be opened by the same scheme.  thank you

Comment: Yes it would but remember the auth code that is usually received does not mean it is the access token. A second layer of defence is to use the auth code to get access token using a client secret and I am sure the other app won't be having this secret. This implementation is again specific to my use case but you get the idea :)

Comment: I see, though your client secret is probably stored in the app so can be theoretically decompiled and retrieved, and then we're back to the same problem.. 
But we can simply use Digital Asset Link to solve the problem of having the scheme open multiple apps instead of only ours. But - in that case the scheme must start with "https://...." to verify the domain with the host. 
So this is the only solution I guess. I really see no benefit to using AppAuth in any case.. the actual implementation doesn't seem so hard to be having to resort to 3-rd party libraries.

Comment: Yes, AppAuth is totally not needed and there are few tricks that can be use to fetch secret dynamically using asymmetric encryption. Coming to "https://" scheme, if anyone using Firebase auth providers will have to go web scheme route anyways. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on the role of AppAuth libraries:

- Standards Based Mobile Security - as covered in [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252)
- Implements the recommended flow of Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Login via System Browser (login via Web Views is not recommended)
- As a Certified Library it can be Good Security Advertising for yout company
- Good Login Usability - stuff like Password Autofill can work

It is hard work to integrate the libraries reliably though. Choosing a solution always involves trade offs based on what you and your stakeholders care most about. If it helps, I have some detailed but visual blog posts and an app you can run, to help in your evaluation:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android)
- [Blog Posts](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for the Blog, I discover your blog 2 weeks ago, I think it is one of the most complete guidelines about OAuth2 on Mobile till now, highly recommend it for anyone who wants to deeply understand about OaAuth2 on mobile.